# Arduino: Putting servos in my class causes them to rotate all the way to one side

Tags: arduino

I am trying to create a new class that controls two servos.
My code compiles just fine. However, when I run it, the servos just turn all the way to one direction. This seems to happen when I try instantiating the class (when in the constructor, I attach the servos in the class to pins).

In My class's header file, I have
[UPDATED]

```
#ifndef ServoController_h
#define ServoController_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Servo.h>

class ServoController
{
    public:
        ServoController(int rotateServoPin, int elevateServoPin);
        void rotate(int degrees);
        void elevate(int degrees);
    private:
        Servo rotateServo;
        Servo elevateServo;
        int elevationAngle;
        int azimuthAngle;
};

#endif
```

Code so far for my Class:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "ServoController.h"

ServoController::ServoController(int rotateServoPin, int elevateServoPin)
{
    azimuthAngle = 0;
    elevationAngle = 0;
    elevateServo.attach(elevateServoPin);
    rotateServo.attach(rotateServoPin);
}


void ServoController::rotate(int degrees)
{
    //TO DO
    rotateServo.write(degrees); 
}


void ServoController::elevate(int degrees)
{
    //TO DO
    elevateServo.write(degrees);    
}
```

And finally my arduino sketch so far is just:

```
#include <ServoController.h>
#include <Servo.h>

ServoController sc(2 , 3);

void setup()
{

}

void loop()
{
}
```

I'm pretty sure the circuit I am using is fine, since if I do not use my class, and just use the servo library directly in my arduino file, the servos move correctly.

any ideas why this might happen?

[UPDATE]

I actually got this working. In my constructor, I have removed the lines to attach the servos to pins. Instead, I have added another method to my class which does the attachment.

```
ServoController::ServoController(int rotateServoPin, int elevateServoPin)
{
    azimuthAngle = 0;
    elevationAngle = 0;
//  elevateServo.attach(elevateServoPin);
//  rotateServo.attach(rotateServoPin);
}


void ServoController::attachPins(int rotateServoPin, int elevateServoPin)
{
    azimuthAngle = 0;
    elevationAngle = 0;
    elevateServo.attach(elevateServoPin);
    rotateServo.attach(rotateServoPin);

}
```

I then call this in my sketch's setup() function:

```
void setup()
{
  sc.attachPins(2,3);

}
```

It seems like if I attach my servos outside of the setup() function, my problem occurs.

[UPDATE July 27 9:13PM]

Verified something with another test:

I created a new sketch where I attached a servo before setup():

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo0;
servo0.attach(2);

void setup()
{

}


void loop() // this function runs repeatedly after setup() finishes
{
  servo0.write(90);
  delay(2000);  
  servo0.write(135);
  delay(2000);
  servo0.write(45);
  delay(2000);
}
```

When I try to compile, Arduino throws an error:

"testservotest:4: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token"

So there was an error, but it was not thrown when the attach method was called from a class

Thanks very much

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing something bad accidentally with the two `Servo` objects? Like premature destruction, attaching them to the same pin, etc.?

Comment: You need to post actual code where you are instantiating your class, above looks fine to me. May be it is something else.

Comment: In the code provided you never actually set the set the position of the Servos.  So they are presumably in an undefined initial state.

Comment: In my setup(), I have added

    sc.rotate(90);
    sc.elevate(45);

but still the same thing happens.

Thanks

Comment: I actually got this working. In my constructor, I have removed the lines to attach the servos to pins. Instead, I have added another method to my class called attachServos(int rotateServoPin, int elevateServoPin) which does the attachment. I then call this in my setup() function. It seems like if I attach my servos outside of the setup() function, my problem occurs. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `servo0.attach()` needs to be inside the setup routine:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo0;

void setup(){
    servo0.attach(2);
}
```

As you discovered with your attachServo routine. You don't need the extra routine, just call attach method inside the setup.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want it in a class, you will have to have a method in the class to do the pin assignment, and call this method either in `setup()` (one time assignment) or in `loop()` (dynamic assignment during program execution).

Pin assignment cannot be done in the constructor of a global variable when using the `Servo.h` library as the timer used to manage the servo output get corrupted between the time you create the object and the time `setup()` is executed.